# Nginx file redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect

my file on image folder (http://domain.com/images/myfile.jpg) has been accessed by some websites using http://domain.com/images/myfile.jpg?bla=blabla. how to redirect http://domain.com/images/myfile.jpg?bla=blabla to http://domain.com/images/myfile.jpg via nginx?

Thank in advanced

Found it

```
location ~ ^/images {
        if ($is_args != "")
{
rewrite ^ $uri? permanent;
}
}
```

Comment: If it's about caching, you could have /images use a different cache-key (without the query args).

Comment: would you please give example?

Comment: location ~ ^/images { proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$uri; } # don't use $args when checking cache.

Answer (score 1):

But for what? The file myfile.jpg the file will be opened with any parameters, added after ? in uri. Anyway, 404 will not raised. ?bla=blabla not part of path to file myfile.jpg on disk for nginx in this case. It's just a variable $args in terms of nginx config.

Comment: I've got about 500 hits/second using ?bla=blabla and it not served from cache. So i think if it will redirect to myfile.jpg my server resource will not get problem